# How to get UITableView to reload properly?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating an exercise based app in iOS.  I feature that I would like to include is a favorites list.  As it currently stands, I have an exercise library where you can tap a button and add it to a favorites list which is accessed through a navigation controller.  I am able to properly pass titles to a store which are then placed in the favorites table view. I can load the specific `exerciseViewController` based on the title of the table view cell and save between run.  However, I have a problem when I try to delete exercises. I have been struggling for hours.

**This is the scenario:**

I have added two exercises to my favorites: `exercise A` which is in the first row, and `exercise B` which is in the second.  However, when the favorites list is accessed, I select `exercise A` to view its details, and decide to unfavorite it, and navigate back (go back) to the favorites list, it is not updated properly.  While it correctly loads the number of rows (which is now 1), it still shows `exercise A` title (it should show `exercise B` title).  But when I navigate all the way back to the home page, and select the favorites exercise, it shows correctly-now only showing the `exercise B` title.  I have tried calling `[[self tableview] reload]` in `viewWillAppear` (this seems to be the most common answer), writing notifications, protocols, etc. and am still having this problem.  The only time it seems to work properly is when the favorites list is accessed through the home page and `viewDidLoad` is called.

How can I get the table to show properly when the table appears and not having to load?

Favorites tableview

```
FavsVC.m  
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    NSLog(@"APPEARING");
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        NSArray *fav = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"];
        NSString *name = [fav objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = name;
    }
    return cell;
}

//This the method is in my store, and gets called when I click on an exercise to add or delete.
- (id)addToFavorites:(NSString *)title
{
    favoriteTitles = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"];
    if ([favoriteTitles containsObject:title]) {
        NSLog(@"exercise removed");
        //[favoriteTitles removeObject:title];

        NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:favoriteTitles];
        [newArray removeObject:title];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newArray forKey:@"Favorites"];  //newArray
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"exercise added");
        //[favoriteTitles addObject:title];

        NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:favoriteTitles];
        [newArray addObject:title];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newArray forKey:@"Favorites"];  //newArray
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't create new cells each and every time, that's why you end up fetching "the wrong cells". You use reusablecells, which doesn't get created each time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, rather modified. The reason is that the `UITableView` only stores the cells that are actually on the screen for memory purposes. Use this instead.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
            // Only create a new cell if it's nil
        }
        // Now you have a reference to the cell. Set its variables.
        NSArray *fav = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"];
        NSString *name = [fav objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = name;
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be notified that your view controller is going to be presented? Just use `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

```
// Somewhere in a table view controller
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
// -------------------------------------------------------
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController    
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     // Your code to update the table view
}
```

Don't forget to set your table view controller to conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

The other option is to trigger the reloading of the table prompt after some changes were made to a related content, in your case in favorites view controller.

But I personally like the first approach more as you have a loose coupling here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the if not statement causing the cell already made to refresh     you don't need your if not statement you just need to load the table from the data

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

        UITableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

//I would probably make a property for array... not create it here
 NSArray *fav = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Favorites"];
  if(fav){
        NSString *name = [fav objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = name;
  }
    return cell;
}
```

also how are you dismissing your favorites view?

is your viewWillAppear: method being called?

//check the nib also default should be YES but check your awake from nib if you have one

```
 - (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;    

}
```